# JQuery stops working when I return to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I implemented a script which load another page without refresh the page and everything works as expected. But I have a bug/problem: if I try to go from "index.html" to "about.html" page (for example) and return to the "index.html", the jquery function on the index page to hide the elements between `<p></p>` tags stops working :(
Anyone know why this happens and the most important how to fix it?

This is my index page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>PAGE1!</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
@import url(css.css);
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>​​​​​
    <div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">welcome</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="terms.html">terms</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
    <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
    <p>Click me away!</p>
    <p>Click me too!</p>
</div>

​​​​​</body></html>
```

This is the about page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>  

<div id="content">
    <p>ABOUT HERE.</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This my JS code which load the page without refresh:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('#nav li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

});
```

});

Thanks in advance, guys!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it happens is because jQuery functions don't work off the bat with new DOM elements so you need to use the `on` function, assuming you are using a version of jQuery > 1.7, if not, you need to use the `live` function instead.

Replace

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").on("click", "p", function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Or, for older versions of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").live("click", function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you could also place the p hiding function in your existing `loadContent` function:

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());

    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: syntax error in `load` callback, either remove `()` from `showNewContent()` or wrap in anonymous function

Comment: any errors in your browser's console? Also, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @martincarlin87 I'm using the 1.2.3

Comment: @martincarlin87 I changed the Jquery version and work!! Thank you, guy, you are amazing!

Comment: ok, that's quite an old version you are using there, I'd recommed updating but I have updated my answer, it's the part with the `live` function. - just seen your comment, no problem, glad it's working now!